# six 1.4.1 is installed but six>=1.5.2 is required by set(['OpenSSL']) in mac OS sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, twilio, macos-sierra

I am trying to install Twilio using `sudo pip install twilio` but it fails with below error logs:

```
Processing dependencies for twilio
error: six 1.4.1 is installed but six>=1.5.2 is required by set(['pyOpenSSL'])
```

I also tried `sudo easy_install twilio`.

Is it OS restriction?
I am first time using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried below command and it works.

```
sudo pip install twilio --ignore-installed six
```